# How can i come to know app is not installed first time on a device iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to store some value when app is installed first time. 
So when user delete and re install that app . read that value and take actions accordingly.
Is there any way ?

Scenario: 
App installed first time store value somewhere.
User deletes app from iPhone.
Re install app again.
Read that stored value. ?

Is this possible ?

Comment: You didnt get my question.Anything saved to User Defaults deleted when app is uninstalled.

Comment: Keychain data is not UserDefualts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the Keychain to store your data, because the Keychain items are not deleted even if the app is Uninstalled or removed.
This Api will help a lot [Link](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore), have a look

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, You can directly refer [Keychain Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW30) from Apple Documentation.